# Sorting of list of arrays in descending order of sum of absolute values of array

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I want to sort a list of arrays in descending order of sum of absolute values of arrays in python. For example input array=[[1, 2, -3, -4], [-2, 3, -1, 5]]
I want to sort it and answer should be
output array=[[-2, 3, -1, 5],[1, 2, -3, -4]]

Answer (score 1):

use `key` in `sort` function to sort the array based  on the `sum` of their values in decending order

```
 array=[[1, 2, -3, -4], [-2, 3, -1, 5]] 
 array.sort(key=lambda x: sum(map(lambda xy:abs(xy), x)), reverse=True)
 print(array)
 # output [[-2, 3, -1, 5],[1, 2, -3, -4]]
```

Comment: This is not correct, It needs to sum the abs values, not just values

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
array=[[1, 2, -3, -4], [-2, 3, -1, 5]]

res=sorted(array, key = lambda x: sum([abs(k) for k in x]))[::-1]

>>> print(res)

[[-2, 3, -1, 5], [1, 2, -3, -4]]
```